# Is there a difference between a power supply's input ground and output ground?

Tags: power-supply, ground, grounding

Are `VIN-` and `VOUT-` equivalent? That is, can I power a device using `VOUT+` and `VIN-`? Or are the two grounds different?

The picture below is of a random boost converter. For some power supplies, I have been able to measure continuity (using a multimeter) between the two grounds, while for others I have not.

[image: generic boost converter]

Comment: It isn't always the case, but it is sometimes the case...

Comment: This looks like a plain non-isolated converter so it probably is, but you can only be sure if you measure it.

Comment: What happens if you use the input ground in an isolated converter?

Comment: Do you mean AC power supplies?

Comment: @JetBlue An isolated converter is isolated. The primary point behind its design and cost is that the input and output are totally isolated, with independent grounds.

Comment: @nanofarad Why is having independent grounds desirable?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The comment by \@Unimportant cleared up a bit of my confusion by mentioning **isolation**

Comment: @JetBlue Because you can't entirely count on AC mains "safety ground" being either safe or grounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're discussing is the difference between an isolated and unisolated converter.

Isolation removes any common connection between input and output and that's the difference, end of !

BTW, it's inaccurate to talk of a converter being a power *SUPPLY*. A converter merely changes voltage and current, it doesn't actually provide the *SUPPLY* of power that's 'upstream' of it.

Answer (score 0):

Dc-dc modules generally work on voltages below SELV (Safety Extra-Low Voltage) - that is, below 60V - so they don’t require isolation between the primary and secondary. The 60V limit is considered ‘touch-safe’ and not likely to pose a shock hazard.

Power modules designed to operate off the line use voltages that exceed the SELV limit, so for safety reasons they must isolate the line input from the output, usually with a transformer. Further, the line-powered sections of these supplies are physically isolated either by shielding or through enclosure design (or both), and the module must be certified to meet applicable safety standards, such as IEC 60950.

Answer (score 0):

The particular module shown uses a Xian Aerosemi [MT3608](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811151539_XI-AN-Aerosemi-Tech-MT3608_C84817.pdf) chip, and the input (-) and output (-) **are**, in fact, common.

[image]

The schematic is as above with a USB connector on the input except R1/R2 are a fixed 2.4K resistor plus a 100K trimpot.